# HTML: Know the Absolute Position of a Centered Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Let say I got this: http://puu.sh/6rqZc.jpg

How can I know the x/y or left/top properties of my canvas assuming that it is centered via this:

```
#canvas-container {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Note: `$('#myCanvas')[0].style.top returns ""`

Comment: Have you tried with the offset method in jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) which will return the coordinates of the element relative to the document:

```
var eTop = $('#myCanvas').offset().top,
    eLeft = $('#myCanvas').offset().left;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `.offset()` or `.position()`:

if you need absolute left/top values:

```
var offLeft = $('#myCanvas').offset().left;
var offTop = $('#myCanvas').offset().top;
```

if you need relatively positioned elem's left/top values:

```
var posLeft = $('#myCanvas').position().left;
var posTop = $('#myCanvas').position().top;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using JQuery

```
$('#myCanvas').eq(0).offset();

// or

$('#myCanvas:first').offset();
```

Comment: No, actually if you see the original post. The user is trying to access maybe the first child element of this id. So, I introduced the eq() and first()